# resizing a UIImageView using Core Animation

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nstimer

I would like to increase the height of a `UIImageView` with every animation frame using Core Animation. Is there any way to do this?

I have done this using an `NSTimer`. I set the `UIImageView` contentMode to scalingMode and then with each tick of the timer i was incrementing the height.

Is there a cleaner, high level way of doing this using Core Animation?

Thanks,
Harikant Jammi

Answer (score 0):

With Core Animation, you would  generally pick a desired size, and a duration, and the system will figure out the keyframes to get you there. You CAN enter a bunch of interim points, and a bunch of times, but you won't be able to get exactly to the set-each-frame-value-precisely point. The system will do it's best to make it smooth.